# Different Sprites for Particles in Three JS

Tags: three.js, particles

The Idea is to split an image into small tiles, this should get achieved by using always the same image but changing the offset of the used image for each sprite. The following code works but is very slow.

Ok I updated the code as follows:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 85, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
camera.position.z = 100;
camera.position.x = 40;
camera.position.y = 30;

scene = new THREE.Scene();


var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var rowCount= 73;
var columnCount=83;

var material = {};
var particles = {};
var geometry = {};
var texture = {};

imageCount = 0;

// DOES NOT WORK
// var originalTexture = textureLoader.load('textures/sprites/full-size.png');

for(i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
  for(j=0;j<columnCount;j++){

    // DOES NOT WORK
    // texture[imageCount] = originalTexture.clone();
    texture[imageCount] = textureLoader.load('textures/sprites/full-size.png');
    texture[imageCount].repeat.set(1/columnCount, 1/rowCount);
    texture[imageCount].offset.y = 1/rowCount * i;
    texture[imageCount].offset.x = 1/columnCount * j;

    geometry[imageCount] = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    var x = j*2;
    var y = i*2;
    var z = 1;
    vertices.push( x, y, z );
    vertice1 = [];
    geometry[imageCount].addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([x, y, z], 3 ) );

    material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 2, map: texture[imageCount], depthTest: true, transparent: false } );
    particles = new THREE.Points( geometry[imageCount], material );
    scene.add(particles);
    imageCount++;

  }
}

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

This splits an image into tiles, defined in rowCount and columnCount. Only problem with this solution is, that it is very slow. The uncommented line, where I try to clone the texture does not work.

Any suggestions?

Here is a working demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/zy2rt9eg/

It works ok for small amount of particles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the same geometry for each material, which means you're causing points to overlap, thus only showing the last one added to the scene. You should use a different geometry for each `THREE.Points` so each point gets its own unique position.

Also, to avoid calling `.load()` for each texture, you could use the [`.clone()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.clone) method for everything after the first one:

```
texture[0] = textureLoader.load('textures/sprites/256.png');
texture[1] = texture[0].clone();
texture[2] = texture[0].clone();
texture[3] = texture[0].clone();
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I updated the code above. Now it is very slow, I think the approach is somehow wrong.

Comment: Ah, yes. Your JSfiddle is trying to animate 600 different `Points`, which is slow because each new `Points` object needs to have its transformation matrix updated, then rendered one at a time. You need a more advanced approach, which creates a single Points object with custom attributes to offset a single texture. Not sure if you know how to write custom shaders, but these examples animate thousands of points via custom attributes: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=custom#webgl_custom_attributes_points